# display data on another page

Tags: sqlite, android-intent

I have a program which requires the user to key-in data. My database is working fine though; I can view all records made.

However, the past record is being displayed at the bottom of my add button: [image]

my question is, is there any way to change so that when I clicked "Add", it goes to another page and load the data instead?

Comment: Yes, you could, but... what about **usability**? Back and forth, back and forth, ... It's probably better to have a Toast showing the last inserted data and then a have button to show all the data together (or, better, filtered by some criterion)

Comment: my program is designed such that the user only needs to use it once a month, so, its not gonna be back and forth, back and forth..

Comment: So, the user inserts 1 row of data each month and then forgets the app? Let's tell about **utility**, then. Would you buy an app just to use it once in a month?

Comment: Another page requires creating another activity. What specific problem do you have with that?